# How to access playlists on Galaxy Tab?

Tags: android

I have created some playlists in the Music application on a Galaxy Tab, but they did not appear in MediaStore.Audio.Playlists. I've noticed that the music app on Galaxy Tab is different than the default one. Maybe, it stores playlists in some other way?

Any ideas on how to access playlists created in that Galaxy Tab-specific Music app?

Comment: Have you download their SDK addon? I guess there will be clues right there.